# htaccess rewrite url by matching part of the url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have been fiddling around with my rewrite rules to cover a domain's content being moved to a different domain. The original domain has new content that isn't being redirected.
I don't want a blanket rewrite from domain to domain as I have other formats being redirected and need to leave to new content alone.
The old urls are being redirected with no problem except for 1 batch of static urls with no extension or parameters.

The old url format:

```
http://olddomain/(variable string)-c2x(variable integers)
```

The new url format:

```
http://newdomain/(variable string)-c2x(variable integers)
```

The only constant to match is the -c2x so I need to redirect all the urls that match the constant part and wild card the variable parts

I have tried various combinations of rewrite matching including (.*)-c2x(.*) to rewrite the url to $1-c2x$2 but I am clearly loosing the plot.

What format should I be following for the rule?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.+?-c2x http://newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: This works if the url includes the www subdomain but not without

Comment: used this and now I am sorted... I think... thanks:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.+?-c2x http://newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R=301,NE]